# Applying binding to knockoutjs ViewModel in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to apply knockout bidding to a modal popup.

I have the fowlling **ViewModel**:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.radioSelectedOption = ko.observable("optionFreeText");


    // It only show textarea when free text message option value is selected
    self.hasFreTextMessageSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.radioSelectedOption() === "optionFreeText");
    });    
}
```

And the **HTML Modal** below:

```html
<section id="test-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Enviar Mensagem</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tipo de Mensagem</label>
                <div class="radio-list">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio"  data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOption" name="optionsRadiosMessageType" id="optionRadioFreeText" value="optionFreeText" class="make-switch optionsRadiosMessageType" checked>
                        Livre
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio"  data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOption" name="optionsRadiosMessageType" id="optionRadioStateRefresh" value="optionStateRefresh" class="make-switch optionsRadiosMessageType">
                        Pedido de Estado
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div for="textareaFreeText" class="form-group" data-bind='visible: hasFreTextMessageSelected'>
                <label>Texto</label>
                <textarea id="textareaFreeText" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn blue">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then in the event **on document ready**:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModal());
```

When I run the code the first time it works perfectly but after the first modal dispose it stop working. The ViewModel is never updated after the first dispose, but I can get the old values.

It looks like the binding it is removed (but it isn't). If I try to binding it again I got the knockout exception "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"...

Comment: When you close the module does it remove itself from the DOM entirely, or does it just get hidden?  If it gets hidden, everything you have is still bound to it, and would cause that exception.

Comment: It's hidden. The modal popup uses the html area-hidden="false/true" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have a lot of typos here that tend to break Knockout bindings.

For instance:

1. You define `var ViewModel = function () {...}`

   - but then pass in `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModal());`
2. Your view model uses the observable `self.radioSelectedOption`

   - but your databinding uses `data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionMessage"`
3. In your ViewModel, you check if the radio button has the value  `(self.radioSelectedOption() === "optionPreDefined"`

   - but that value isn't defined anywhere in your markup.

Once you shore up those issues, the resulting code should work:

## [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p4nyV/)

Also, you don't have to pass in `this` as the second parameter to a computed property when using the [`var self = this`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#a-popular-convention-that-simplifies-things) trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KyleMit. About 1, 2 and 3, I have it right in my code, but when I copied it to here I removed a few components and refactored others... I tested your code without changing anything and the bug remains... So I think that some of the scripts that I'm using it is breaking the bidding. BTW, thanks for the tip about passing this when using self trick!

Comment: @jbatista, Can you posts the minimum necessary code to reproduce the issue, perhaps in a working fiddle?  If it different enough from your original code, it might be worth marking this question as answered and asking another one specific to whatever interference is occurring.